# Developing and distributing framework in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

I am developing an SDK that should support iOS 8 and up. The prodcut is an SDK that will be used by customers.

As I understand, I can either craete a fat static framework or a fat dynamic (embeded) framework. So my customers can use one framework for simulator and for distribution.

When I created a fat framework incuding support for ios simulator. The customers must strip the simulator binaries before uploading their app to the AppStore.
Is that the recommended method?

Should I prefer creating old style static framework to avoid the simulator binaries stripping? What are teh disadvantage of that?

What other vendors providing?

Answer (score 0):

You should try `-lipo` command to produce an universal version.